# Print output from process launched from groovy

Tags: groovy, process

In a groovy script I start an external process with:

```
def proc = command.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput( System.out, System.err )
proc.waitFor()
println "\nDone. Exit value: ${proc.exitValue()}"
```

But how do I write the output from the application if it fails?

There is:

```
  proc.errorStream
  proc.outputStream
```

But maybe the output is automatically written when using the `consumeProcessOutput` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass `System.out` and `System.err` to `consumeProcessOutput()`, the output and error streams will both printed out automatically.  If you want to capture it, pass in your own output steams:

```
def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
def err = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
def proc = command.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
proc.waitFor()

println "error stream was ${err.toString()}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ‘running-forever’ process (this happens on some Windows env when output exceeds 4096 bytes) add initial size to ByteArrayOutputStream

```
def initialSize = 4096
def out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(initialSize)
def err = new ByteArrayOutputStream(initialSize)
def proc = command.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
proc.waitFor()
```